# Sorting in Advanced Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have a Advanced Datagrid with sorting. I think it is string sorting by default. But I need the sorting in number. How can I achieve the number sorting?

For example: I have row numbers like 1 to 100 . I need number sorting like 1,10,100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your advancedDataGridColumn add a sortCompareFunction:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn sortCompareFunction="NumberSorter" 
sortDescending="true" dataField="number" headerText="Formal Name" width="280"/>
```

Add the function somewhere in your scripts

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil
        public function NumberSorter(itemA:Object, itemB:Object):int{
        return ObjectUtil.numericCompare(itemA.number, itemB.number);
    }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your underlying data source is a simple Array of numbers, you can simply call [sort()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Array.html#sort%28%29):

```
myArray.sort(Array.NUMERIC);
```

If your numbers are in a specific field for each array entry object, you could instead use [sortOn()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Array.html#sortOn%28%29):

```
myArray.sortOn("rowNumberField", Array.NUMERIC);
```